# A clarification request for declined flag

Tags: discussion, flagging

[This question](https://serverfault.com/questions/894901/windows-server-2008%e3%81%8b%e3%82%89%e3%81%ae%e7%a7%bb%e8%a1%8c%e3%81%ab%e3%81%a4%e3%81%84%e3%81%a6)(For >10k) was originally posted in Japanese language. Due to non-latin characters in title and body, it was picked by SmokeDetector in [Charcoal HQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42593626#42593626). After looking into the translated version and finding it fine, I [suggested an edit](https://serverfault.com/review/suggested-edits/355651) with English version of the question.

However, this post was deleted and my suggested edit couldn't get reviewers. OP of the post has [posted the same question again](https://serverfault.com/questions/894902/about-migrating-from-windows-server-2008), but in English. So, I flagged it to notify moderator about re-posting and my pending suggested edit and to ask them to take a proper action. This flag was declined with a message,

> declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

Though, I have no issue with the declined flag, but this reason is quite ambiguous. Therefore, I'd like to know why exactly my flag was declined, just for the future reference. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, let me thank you for taking the time to translate and edit the original post! It's appreciated, even if it turned out to be unused in the end.

That said: The most important reason your flag got declined is that the new question already has an answer and we can't move the answer over to the old question. But I would have denied the flag anyway because frankly, this is just not worth the effort, both yours and mine. You wrote a lengthy flag comment, copied various links around and now even wrote an even longer meta post and I would have to undelete, accept the edit, close one as a duplicate, leave a comment to explain, and all this while there is a perfectly fine question already available. Deleting and re-asking is not optimal, but certainly not worth that much effort!

Comment: Oh! No problem! I raised the flag when there was no answer. And I honestly didn't see it later. I guess [this is gonna be pending till eternity](https://serverfault.com/review/suggested-edits/355651). ;-)

Comment: Oh,  I didn't know suggested edits keep pending even if the original post gets deleted. I accepted the edit now :)